# Google Maps & Places API suggest business based on geolocation android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

So I've been playing around with both Geocode, places(nearbysearch, text search) to somehow figure out the business you're at if you're inside the store.

My issue is that if I'm in Walmart (or other big stores) it's **really** difficult to get the place_id of Walmart.  It provides results that simply don't work.

I've tried upping the radius to find the street address then run another query based on street address (which still fails to work) but this can easily get out of hand.

I'm hoping to get the place_id based on geolocation of the user so I can get relevant info about the business.

I just want an easy automated "hey based on your location it looks like your in ___ store.  Is this correct?"

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace()` is for.  See https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/current-place.